# EF 7 .NET Core tools error

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I have created a new .NET Core project with `dotnet new -t lib` command. It's a class library for my EF Context. This is my `project.json`:

```
    {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run `dotnet restore` command I'm getting this error:

```
error: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 1.0.0-preview2-final is not compatible with netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 1.0.0-preview2-final supports:
```

How I can use EF Code First with netstandard1.6?

Comment: Beware that using the tooling for Enity Framework does not support class libaries yet So doing `dotnet ef` will fail. See https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet.html#targeting-class-library-projects-is-not-supported for workarounds.

Comment: @JohanB It is partly addressed by using `--startup-project` workaround, for example: `dotnet ef --startup-project ../ProjectThatCanRunCommand/ migrations add InitDb`, take a look at this: [Parameterize directories used by dotnet-ef](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/pull/5680)

Comment: @HamidMosalla This is a solution I've been looking for. Could you update your answer with this comment so I could mark it as a right answer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [this](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/rc1-rc2-upgrade.html#dnx-commands-net-cli-asp-net-core-projects-only), The `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"` should be registered in a tools section in project.json:

```
{
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"description": "Class Library",
"frameworks": {
  "netstandard1.6": {
   "imports": [
     "dnxcore50"
   ]
 }
},

 "dependencies": {
 "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
 "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
 "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0"
},
"tools": {
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
 }
}
```

Also it is a good idea to use [imports](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/rc1-rc2-upgrade.html#using-imports-in-project-json), because some of the EF Core’s dependencies still don't support .NETStandard, but in your case I checked and it works even without imports.

Regarding the Johan B's comment, which states ef tools cannot be used with class libraries for now, it is partly addressed by using `--startup-project` workaround, for example: `dotnet ef --startup-project ../ProjectThatCanRunCommand/ migrations add InitDb`, more info: [Parameterize directories used by dotnet-ef.](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/pull/5680)